# How to query Mongoose with .sort()

Tags: mongoose

I know it's a simple question but in mongoose 4.0.1, even with the API doc I'm not able to query my Model and sort the results.

I have a collection of Invoices and I'd like to find which one is the "better" invoice, with the higher value (field total).

The Model :

```
var invoiceSchema = new Schema ({
    employee : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee' },
    customer : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Customer' },
    products : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' },
    priced : Number,
    qty : Number,
    total: Number,
    date : Date
});
```

How I create an Invoice :

```
exports.createInv = function (req, res) {
    Invoice.create({
        employee : req.body.employee,
        customer : req.body.customer,
        products  : req.body.products,
        priced : req.body.priced,
        qty : req.body.qty,
        total : req.body.priced*req.body.qty,
        comment : req.body.comment,
        date : req.body.date
    }, function(err) {
    if (err)
        return res.send(err);
    });
}
```

The query should look like that :

```
Invoice
    .find()
    .sort(-total)
    .exec(function(err, inv) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err)
        } else {
            res.json(doc);
            console.log(doc);
        }
    })
```

But it doesn't work :)

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` takes a `String` or an `Object`

```
Invoice
.find()
.sort("-total")
.exec(function(err, inv) {
    if (err) {
        return res.send(err)
    } else {
        res.json(doc);
        console.log(doc);
    }
})
```